# Why would a website behave strange in live environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a website that behaves as expected in local environment but not while it is live (I have tried two different web servers)

I think problem is javascript related.

Link: http://tevfikiltermimarlik.com/

when you just go to that url every thing is normal. A carousel is shown.
But.
If you click "HAKKIMIZDA" (bottom) again everything is normal.
after that, if you click "ANASAYFA" (homepage) now the carousel doesn't show.
And finally, If you hit F5 everything is OK again.

Another strange problem is that:
if you click "REFERANSLARIMIZ" that loading icon ("YUKLENIYOR") never goes away as long as you dont hit F5.

Those problems are really very strange to me. What may cause these to happen?

Comment: It is not forbidden, but you should post the related code too and not only a link. See [Something in my project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I really don't know where is the problem in the code. Those problems are so strange that I cant predict the reason. And sharing the full code is meaningless I think.

Comment: It looks like the code is possibly being somewhat cached and is not reinitiating itself.  You might have to call the carousel again when you click back?

Comment: idk if its related, but I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live" which is caused by colorbox using  jquery's deprecated `live` method.

Comment: also note that this site depends on jQuery 2.0, which no longer supports IE < 9. But.. you have other stuff loaded conditionally if its < 9. I'd include jquery 1.9.x conditionally as well, or just get rid of all conditional comments, since they won't be of much help if you don't have jQuery.

Comment: @ZachL it was jquery 1.7.x I have tried my luck before I fixed it. No problems left. But I still wonder why would it work in local with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the theme's page on themeforest - it looks like back in March they fixed some Ajax and colorbox bugs. Maybe this was one of them. Is this site perhaps using an older version? I couldn't find the version number anywhere in the source.

http://themeforest.net/item/truestory-fullscreen-html5-template/3902394

Comment: I disabled ajax_loading (whatever it is) and problem is fixed. There was use_page_ajax_loading:true andd I turned it off.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the live site with Firebug and noticed on styles.css `li, #home-slider .slides li img` line 2409 it has the property:

```
display:none;
```

When I remove that CSS the images show up as they should.

Comment: This is probably due to the theme's "loading" indicator effect. It keeps everything "display:none" until they load. From now on I am not interested in fixing this stupid theme. I really wonder why would a website work flawless in local environment but not while it is live.

Comment: @HasanAyan something else is going on. "local" html is parsed no differently than "live" html. What is the site built with? You say its a theme? Which theme?

Comment: @ZachL that is the thing that drives me crazy. It includes javascript, html and css codes only. It's the theme called truestory. I have no idea about the theme. My friend asked me fix his problem. and he also uploaded theme's own demo page. It has problems too. tevfikiltermimarlik.com/demo